# React Native, redux form, native base - onChange(event) function doesnt work,undefined is not an object evaluating event.target.value

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-form

**CHANGED, STILL NO ANSWER**
I followed this example:
https://jsfiddle.net/4np9u17g/11/
I want to make it like there - after inputing value focus should go to next input. I use new syntax of refs and redux form, what am i doing wrong?

```
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.field1 = React.createRef();
    this.field2 = React.createRef();
    this.field3 = React.createRef();
    this.field4 = React.createRef();
    this.field5 = React.createRef();
    this.field6 = React.createRef();
  }
```

On change function (I made it really simple for now):

```
 onChange = (text) => {
   if (text.length === 1) {
    this.field3.focus();
}
```

};

Input component:

```
  InputComponent = ({ input, meta, ...rest }) => (
    <Input {...rest} keyboardType="numeric" maxLength={1} value={input.value} onChangeText={input.onChange} />
  );
```

And finally one of my redux form fields:

```
 <Field
    maxLength={
    id="2"
    ref={this.field1}
    style={styles.input}
    name="pinSix1"
    component={this.InputComponent}
    placeholder="*"
    onChange={this.onChange}
    secureTextEntry
  />
  <Field
    id="3"
    ref={this.field2}
    style={styles.input}
    name="pinSix2"
    component={this.InputComponent}
    placeholder="*"
    onChange={this.onChange}
    secureTextEntry
  />
```

And I get an error

> undefined is not a function (evaluating '_this.field3.focus()')

Comment: There event `onChangeText` in which you get typed value as an argument.
`onChangeText = {(text)=>console.log(text)}`

Comment: @Revansiddh ? I dont understand what you mean and what should I change...

Comment: in `onChange` function, you are receiving direct `value` not an event

Comment: so how i can repair this? currently i have  onChange = (text) => {
    if (text.length === 1) {
      this.field2.focus();
    }
  };
but get error 'undefined is not a function (evaluationg '_this.field2.focus()')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, after hours of struggling here's what I had to do (As i said I am using new syntax of refs, React 16.3). I have created InputComponent with ref passed as props:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Input } from 'native-base';

class InputComponent extends PureComponent {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
  };

  render() {
    const { input, externalRef, ...rest } = this.props;
    return (
      <Input
        {...rest}
        ref={externalRef}
        keyboardType="numeric"
        maxLength={1}
        value={input.value}
        onChangeText={input.onChange}
      />
    );
  }
}

InputComponent.propTypes = {
  input: PropTypes.object,
  externalRef: PropTypes.object,
};

export default InputComponent;
```

Then in my component where pin code inputs are implemented:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.field0 = React.createRef();
    this.field1 = React.createRef();
    this.field2 = React.createRef();
    this.field3 = React.createRef();
    this.field4 = React.createRef();
    this.field5 = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.field0.current._root.focus();
  }

  onChange = (text, val, body, name) => {
    if (text.length === 1 && name !== '6') {
      this[`field${name}`].current._root.focus();
    } else if (text.length === 1 && name === '6') {
      this.field5.current._root.blur();
    }
  };
```

The issue here is was this horrible NativeBase Input which has the focus() and blur() function hard to access.
Finally - one of my six Fields:

```
<Field
   externalRef={this.field0}
   style={styles.input}
   name="1"
   component={InputComponent}
   placeholder="*"
   onChange={this.onChange}
   secureTextEntry
 />
```

Right now when user inputs some numbers it goes to the next input and when he or she inputs in the last Field the blur() function runs.

Answer (score 0):

onChangeText() from TextInput is called with the text string which is inputted into that input field, not with an event object

**Edit**
To answer your question on how to handle this. You will need to edit your onChange handler:

```
onChange = (text) => {
  if (text.length === this.maxLength /* or wherever maxLength comes from */ ) {
    this.refs[nextField].focus()
  }
};
```

Where nextField the name of the next input is, which you provide through the ref prop

You can also see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32748718/react-native-how-to-select-the-next-textinput-after-pressing-the-next-keyboar) for more information:

Comment: I made it the simlest as it is possible to check if it works but still have one error:
  onChange = (text) => {
    if (text.length === 1) {
      this.field3.focus();
    }
  };

I got error 'undefined is not a function (evaluationg '_this.field3.focus()')

Comment: you need to access this.refs['field3'].focus()

Comment: It appears you are right, I edited the link in my answer which refers to a more up to date StackOverflow answer